# throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i just configured my new project and added mongoose and as it seems new release 5.7.4 has a bug in it because of when i use code like this:

```
require('dotenv').config({
    path: '../.env' 
})
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(typeof process.env.MONGO_URI == 'string')
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('con to db established')
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(`db err: ${err.message}`);
    process.exit(-1)
})
const schemas = require('./schemas');
const models = {};
for(let i in schemas){
    models[i] = mongoose.model(i, schemas[i]);
    console.log(i)
}

module.exports = {
    models,
    mongoose,
    connection: mongoose
}
```

and log process.env.MONGO_URI it logs correct url so that means it is gettting variable from .env file correctly and even though i add `"mongodb+srv://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@<CLUSTER>.mongodb.net/MYDBNAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` inside mongoose.connect instead of `process.env.MONGO_URI` it still logs the same, what can i do?

P.S: I am saying that this is `^5.7.4` bug because i have other project initialized with `^5.7.3` and it does not logs error in title & i use following code in both of them

Comment: It seems, you had already opened an issue about this in github, so you had better to use version 5.7.3.

Comment: i already did but i just asked if there was a solution

Comment: Just use 5.7.3 , there is nothing blocking you.

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes i already did LOL thanks for answer btw